# async LINQ query

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

I am working on a LINQ query that should be able to be done async, but it is not evaluating. In trying to fix the issue I found this page:
[MS Page on Client vs Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval)

It states that I should be able to add AsAsyncEnumerable to my LINQ to get it to work. However, it does not even compile.

I have the following that works, but is running synchronously:

```
    AreaLookupTb = _context.AreaLookupTb
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupJoin(_context.LocationTb, a => a.AreaId, b => b.AreaId, (a, b) => new GroupingStats { ID = a.AreaId, Name = a.Name, Description = a.Description, Count = b.Count() })
                    .OrderBy(n => n.Name)
                    .ToList();
```

You would think that all I would need to is this to make it async:

```
    AreaLookupTb = await _context.AreaLookupTb
                    .AsAsyncEnumerable()
                    .GroupJoin(_context.LocationTb, a => a.AreaId, b => b.AreaId, (a, b) => new GroupingStats { ID = a.AreaId, Name = a.Name, Description = a.Description, Count = b.Count() })
                    .OrderBy(n => n.Name)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

Alas, not the case. The error that VS2019 gives me is this:

> Error  CS1061  'IAsyncEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'GroupJoin' and no accessible extension method 'GroupJoin' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's `ToAsyncEnumerable()` not `AsAsyncEnumerable()`.

Comment: Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert all `Enumerable` to `AsyncEnumerable` :

```
AreaLookupTb = await _context.AreaLookupTb
                    .ToAsyncEnumerable()
                    .GroupJoin(_context.LocationTb.ToAsyncEnumerable(), a => a.AreaId, b => b.AreaId, (a, b) => new GroupingStats { ID = a.AreaId, Name = a.Name, Description = a.Description, Count = b.Count() })
                    .OrderBy(n => n.Name)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I have tried a few different ways to correct this, and none have yet to work. When I change the AsEnumerable to ToAsyncEnumerable VS is telling me that it should be AsEnumerable and will not compile. If I do that, I am back to square 1 as stated above. Long story short  this does not work.

Comment: Link to [link](https://github.com/snussel/OpenDurringLockdown) GitHub.